# Convert UTC Time to local Time using time zone info from database

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I have timezone information for a particular record from database as for example **-6** which means **UTC-6**.
How can I use this **-6** to convert my **UTC** time to **UTC-6**?

I think I have to use TimeZoneInfo in c#.
Timezone information is not the same for all records.

Comment: yeah sorry, I was confused by the title

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateTimeOffset to create a date with the offset.

```
var dbDate = myRawDbDate.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unknown ? DateTime.SpecifyKind(myRawDbDate, DateTimeKind.Utc): myRawDbDate;
var localDdate = new DateTimeOffset(dbDate, new TimeSpan(0,6,0)).DateTime;
```

Comment: The date still not being converted to UTC-6 .. DateTime.SpecifyKind(myRawDbDate, DateTimeKind.Utc) this will return UTC local date time.

Comment: Small syntax errors: missing closing parenthesis before `.DateTime`, and the capitalization of `TimeSpan`. You could also use the more readable (to me anyway) `TimeSpan.FromHours(6)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use TimeZoneInfo Class.

```
 var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time"); //UTC-6
 var UTC6date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Yourdate.ToUniversalTime(), timeZone);
```

for more information here is the link. MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835(v=vs.110).aspx

to view all the time zone for UTC-6:00 etc.

Use `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` method.

Sample code :

```
var timeZonList = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

    foreach (var item in timeZonList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(date converted to universal time, "Timezone to convert your date").
```

Hope this helps.